# Upload multiple files in oracle using java servlet

Tags: java, oracle, servlets, file-upload, blob

I want to send email to users which includes multiple attachment files. I am trying to insert data into table and then firing trigger to send mail. I am using two tables one contains all basic mail info like to,cc,bcc & another table contains file's info like name, blob. Both table are joined using mailId.

I just want to know how to send all Files in one go to procedure. Is there any collection available to send files to oracle & again retrieve same in oracle procedure.

Comment: Why do you want to use a trigger? And what does sending an email from Oracle have to do with file uploads or servlets?

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for your reply. Actually sender will upload various documents like (Quotation info, PO info) and then that mail will be sent to supplier. I also need to maintain mail delivery status info. That's why I am using trigger.

Comment: Can anyone help me out?